# Converting Fixed Effects From Linear Mixed Model to Odds Ratio

Tags: mixed-model, linear-model, linear

I am using the R package lme4, to find the fixed effects using a linear mixed model, shown below:

```
model <- lme4::lmer(Appointment.Status ~   Poverty.Status + (1 | PATIENT), 
                              data = data)
```

Is there a way to convert the fixed effect coefficients to odds ratio?

Thank you in advance for the help, and please let me know if I can clarify.

Comment: Is your outcome variable, Appointment.Status, binary? odds ratios are typically used for binary outcomes.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes both the Appointment.Status and Poverty.Status are binary variables. Thank you for allowing me to clarify that.